# How to iter over a dict created by defaultdict?

Tags: python

I am iterating a dict created using the following.

```
 tree = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, partial(defaultdict, list)))
 for dt, hour, value in flat_list:
     tree[dt][hour]=[]
     tree[dt][hour].append(value)
```

My output looks like this:

```
 for k,v in tree.iteritems():
     2012-08-07 defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x1e0a050>, {'17': ['30']})
     2012-08-24 defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x1e0a050>, {'3': ['70']})
```

How do I get rid of this stuff?  How do I iter like a regular dict?:

```
defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x1e0a050>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already iterating over the default dicts like a regular dict, but you are *printing* the defaultdict representation too.

To print these like you would print a regular dict, just turn them back into one:

```
 for k,v in tree.iteritems():
     print k, dict(v)
```

Note that a `defaultdict` is a direct subclass of `dict`, apart from the updated `__getitem__` behaviour and the updated `__repr__` hook<sup>1</sup>, a `defaultdict` behaves *exactly* like a normal `dict` would, certainly when it comes to iterating.

<sup>1<sub>`__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` are overridden too, to create a new `defaultdict` when using the `copy` module. A custom `__reduce__` is provided for the `pickle` module for the same reasons.</sub></sup>